# How can I scrape the "Time" and other data in the advanced details section using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Here is the url that I want to scrape the data 'https://www.blockchain.com/explorer/transactions/btc/43eebdc59c6c5ce948ccd9cf514b6c2ece9f1289f136c2e3d9d69dcd29304142'

I tried to scrape using Beautiful Soup because it doesn't have to open the browser like the Selenium does. So I tried to extract the data from the outer section

```
('section',{'class':'sc-f9148dd7-2 irWxzm'})
```

[the irWxzm section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLtKV.png)
and then tried to find a little bit deeper to the targeted div tag but I don't understand why after I extracted the data from 'section',{'class':'sc-f9148dd7-2 irWxzm'}, it seemed that the data has stopped from the advanced details[the data from irWxzm section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8B00Y.png) and I can't dive deeper to the desired div tag in the first picture.

Here my code that I wrote

```
import requests
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.blockchain.com/explorer/transactions/btc/43eebdc59c6c5ce948ccd9cf514b6c2ece9f1289f136c2e3d9d69dcd29304142' 
res = requests.get(url)
format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'html.parser')

soup2 = soup.find('section',{'class':'sc-f9148dd7-2 irWxzm'})

print(soup2)
```

I tried a lot but it can't find any tag under 'class':'sc-f9148dd7-2 irWxzm' except class="sc-c907597a-0 MqlNG and class="sc-c907597a-3 ctQMfW" according to second picture.

Could you help me find the way to get the data in the advanced details section please.
[desired data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnFnq.png)

Thank you so very much in advance.

Comment: This is a "dynamic" page. The class will vary. You'll need a different strategy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page loads the data from external URL via JavaScript, to load the data you can use next example:

```py
from datetime import datetime

import requests

api_url = "https://www.blockchain.com/explorer/api/transaction?asset=btc&id=43eebdc59c6c5ce948ccd9cf514b6c2ece9f1289f136c2e3d9d69dcd29304142"

data = requests.get(api_url).json()
print(data)
```

Prints:

```
{
    "ticker": "btc",
    "transaction": {
        "txid": "43eebdc59c6c5ce948ccd9cf514b6c2ece9f1289f136c2e3d9d69dcd29304142",
        "size": 381,
        "version": 1,
        "locktime": 0,
        "fee": 170170,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "coinbase": False,
                "txid": "667f2825db6b03e349b5e4be7b4c4c5be266c242a6aaa0218480572ffc5a7b37",
                "output": 0,
                "sigscript": "47304402204ba063dca925f759777ed8818027c421cb4052ecf2e3b980c814bc528c73638e02206a3d58ec92d0be9915c14d6c4cef40a01d301286c90d82c1bcf166db0e94c3bb012103951bbeb5b73e530b6849fca68e470118f4b379ad9126015caf1355dc2a9e8480",
                "sequence": 4294967295,
                "pkscript": "76a9149c8ab044348d826b9ae88d698d575a45a6e8fc6988ac",
                "value": 207730,
                "address": "1FGiZB7K757EUixGcyeyME6Jp8qQZEiUUk",
                "witness": [],
            },
            {
                "coinbase": False,
                "txid": "3c2dc36fd0bebc46062362aff0c4f307d1c99900c5f358fdd37b436a15d37a5f",
                "output": 0,
                "sigscript": "4730440220322e489e971b2c651224c2e03bea408df8c67a0a1c18ddfd20e940d90a8e61990220707ba2431bde31500ebe6a2b3c4a7974b87c4b9ee33849e1453c0831318bed14012103951bbeb5b73e530b6849fca68e470118f4b379ad9126015caf1355dc2a9e8480",
                "sequence": 4294967295,
                "pkscript": "76a9149c8ab044348d826b9ae88d698d575a45a6e8fc6988ac",
                "value": 231716,
                "address": "1FGiZB7K757EUixGcyeyME6Jp8qQZEiUUk",
                "witness": [],
            },
        ],
        "outputs": [
            {
                "address": "1FGiZB7K757EUixGcyeyME6Jp8qQZEiUUk",
                "pkscript": "76a9149c8ab044348d826b9ae88d698d575a45a6e8fc6988ac",
                "value": 269276,
                "spent": True,
                "spender": {
                    "txid": "c7ed715e9f73b2792957af94d3143750525a29f6a62fd6f68d470e56e4bbef7b",
                    "input": 0,
                },
            },
            {
                "address": None,
                "pkscript": "6a208627c703aeac41df8acad1c643d9ee9c2370f9cace1af05a0ac41219116b5e0b",
                "value": 0,
                "spent": False,
                "spender": None,
            },
        ],
        "block": {"height": 756449, "position": 2},
        "deleted": False,
        "time": 1664582470,
        "rbf": False,
        "weight": 1524,
    },
    "rate": 16526.38,
    "latestBlock": 769853,
    "id": "43eebdc59c6c5ce948ccd9cf514b6c2ece9f1289f136c2e3d9d69dcd29304142",
    "description": False,
    "fiat": "USD",
    "labels": {},
}
```

---

To get the time:

```
print(datetime.fromtimestamp(data["transaction"]["time"]))
```

Prints:

```
2022-10-01 02:01:10
```

Comment: oh, it works. Thank you very much.
can you tell me how to see whether the page loads the data from an external URL via JavaScript or not?

Comment: @user20433475 When you press CTRL+U to show source code of the page you will not see any data inside. So the page has to load the data from elsewhere. Open the Web developer tools -> Network Tab (in Chrome/Firefox) and reload the page. You should see all URLs the page is connecting to.

Comment: I see! Really appreciate your help sir, your answer helps me a lot. Thanks for your kindness.